# How to create a value with reference-counted references to itself while checking an already-borrowed field?

Tags: rust, mutable, reference-counting, borrowing, refcell

I'm trying to create a mutable structure `B` which stores instances of other structure `A` that hold references to `B`. I want an implementation such that any mutation done to the original `B` propagates to the references held in the `A`s.

However, during the mutation, I have to check a field from the `B` instance wrapped in `A` instance, thus breaking the "one mutable xor many immutable" rule. I need to borrow immutably while borrowed mutably, but the immutable borrow is internal to the mutating function and does not outlive its scope.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    t: Weak<RefCell<B>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B {
    a: usize,
    item: Option<A>,
}

impl B {
    pub fn mutate(&mut self, item: A) {
        {
            let t = item.t.upgrade().unwrap();

            // This check has to be done.
            //
            assert![t.borrow().a == self.a, "not equal"];
            //      ~~~~~~~~~~ panics on this borrow
        }
        //
        // The immutable borrow should end here.

        self.item = Some(item);
        self.a += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b = B { item: None, a: 0 };

    let bc = Rc::new(RefCell::new(b));

    let f = A {
        t: Rc::downgrade(&bc),
    };

    bc.borrow_mut().mutate(f);

    println!["{:?}", bc.borrow().item.as_ref().unwrap().t.upgrade()];
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17b51e3c467dadde49f5744d8b70a7c1)

It panics with:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'already mutably borrowed: BorrowError'
```

Can these requirements be met using only `Rc<RefCell<B>>`? If not, do I have to sink into `unsafe` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [`RefCell::borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow) say:

> #### Panics
>
> Panics if the value is currently mutably borrowed. For a non-panicking
>   variant, use [`try_borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.try_borrow).

Using `try_borrow` with the knowledge that any existing borrow must be `self` (and thus is equal) allows your code to compile:

```
let eq = t.try_borrow().map_or(true, |v| v.a == self.a);
assert![eq, "not equal"];
```

See also:

- [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)

Comment: That looks promising. However, `try_borrow` would fail even when some other field of `t` is mutably borrowed, right? So if I use this method, I have to watch over the semantics carefully. Thank you very much, however.